# How can I use a src folder library from GitHub

Tags: java, eclipse, zip, src

I am trying to use this library from [github](https://github.com/mrniko/netty-socketio).
They only provide a src folder and there is no compiled JAR that I can use.

My question is, How can I use the library in my Java project in the Eclipse IDE?
I've tried researching but I can't find a single website that doesn't assume I know how to use these types of libraries. It must be something obvious that I'm missing. It would be great if someone could point me in the right direction.

Comment: If you read the readme on that page you'll see they list a maven dependency XML entry. This is the defacto standard for dependency management in java. You set up your project to use maven, it automatically downloads the dependency. Otherwise, download the jar from [maven central](http://search.maven.org)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Clone the project with `git`, then make a build yourself, there is an included `pom.xml` file for maven

**UPDATE**

[link](http://search.maven.org/#artifactdetails%7Ccom.corundumstudio.socketio%7Cnetty-socketio%7C1.6.1%7Cbundle) from maven central

Comment: Or, use maven. Or just download the jar from maven central.

Comment: Thanks! I'm new to Java and don't want to get into building it myself. I'll try this and report back

Answer (score 0):

It's a Maven project. You will have to build it using Maven and then import the build jar from ~/.m2/repository or target directory in your Eclipse project classpath.

Comment: If you're going to use maven there's absolutely no reason to build from source. They publish to maven central and show the dependency entry in the readme

Comment: Wasn't sure if that was built. But looks like it is. You can download the jar from http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.corundumstudio.socketio/netty-socketio/1.6.0